# %HEXADECIMAL% is decoding (%7445% as input results in t445% in PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am handling a scenario in PhP where the input is in %XXXXX% format, where XXXXX can be any number of characters/numbers. The input will be sent to sql for processing (the main intention is to send the input that contains %TEXT% to sql).

What I understand from the scenario is that the input text is being encoded as %257445D%25 and later it is decoded to t445D%. Here the value of ‘%74’ is ‘t’ and in this case any hexa decimal number followed by % gives the decoded form. Here is the ASCII encoding for reference " http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp "

The ultimate goal is to get the output same as input. I dont want the input to be encoded and decoded.

Here is the piece of code:
form:

\
              (ex:%7445% or %anything) \

Getting value: 
$ss= $_GET['name_1'];

Please help me in getting raw data without encoding and decoding the value. I have tried using many scenario’s including the decoded version of htmlentities, utf8_encode, rawurlencode, using regex and replacing strings and many more.

The actual code contains more text boxes and other functions, if one thing works i can replicate the same and make it work for others.

Thank you!

Comment: How that "input" is passed? Where do you get it from?

Comment: input is given through a textbox,

<INPUT TYPE='text' name='name_1'  />\
              (ex:%7445% or %anything) \
              <INPUT TYPE='submit' name=name_pause_type value='Pause'>

here is the code snippet

Comment: so the input is always with % at start and end of string or you could append them before storing in db?

Comment: You're obviously double-decoding the input variable from one of your various attempts. Don't do that. I'd say look into the environments `QUERY_STRING` even for what you actually received. Your question contains insufficient actual code/logic to tell anything concrete.

Comment: the input may have % around the name or it may not have, we wil get that name as it is and send it to database to query on them. When the browser encounters a % followed by special characters then it will encode and map to corresponding character. example: %74 = t , %25 = % and so on.

Comment: @mario : there is no decoding happening, to be specific about the flow, 

The input is given with the % around the "name" i just want to get the value and send it to the db.. Currently I am getting the name using $_GET['name'] which is encoding and decoding and messing up the input.. If the input is %7444% then it should send %7444% rather than encoding itself to t44%